# Web form textarea do not accept "list" in chrome

Tags: html, forms

This going to be weird or definitely godaddy's problem.

The live version is at http://goo.gl/ibxwju.

I have a very simple form as below,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="test-op.php" method="post">
    Remark:<br>
    <textarea name="newremark" style="width:500px" ></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You may try submit anything and the form is working fine, but if your input contain word "**list**" then the chrome browser telling connection was interrupted.

To be clear, my problem is the form cannot accept the word "list"?

***Update: Is not Godaddy problem, tested with firefox no problem. But my chrome 45.0.2454.101 m still give me problem.***

Comment: look like not godaddy problem, I tried firefox no problem. But my chrome ( 45.0.2454.101 m ) give me problem.

Comment: i tried in chrome, Version 46.0.2490.80 , no problem ..

Comment: and am pretty sure that this is NOT a browser related issue. try in incognoto window ?

Comment: incognoto mode same problem

Comment: try in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/jbwc7ab6/ , use the word `list`

Comment: the jsfiddle working fine, tried other web form also no problem, I think I will just ignore this small problem for good, thanks @KishoreSahas for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My observation is that the issue is not dependent to browser / godaddy.

I tried with inputs `list` in http://goo.gl/ibxwju

[image]

Result :

[image]

You may try the below items.

- Try your scenario in http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/jbwc7ab6
- Verify your browser (chrome) for any **extensions** interference.
- Network related items like Firewall policies.
- And possibly check your `test-op.php`